# bootstrap Validator and selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I want to use [this](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/) plugin to validate my forms. My form is consists of many other forms (I am using django) inside tabs. so it looks like this

```
<form action="" id="register-form" method="post">

    <div class="container bg-white">
        <div class="tab-container">
            <div class="tab-content">

                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="client-details">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Personal Data</legend>
                        <span class="help-inline">This are your billing data</span>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_client-first_name">First name:</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_client-first_name" maxlength="40" name="client-first_name" type="text">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_client-middle_name">Middle name:</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_client-middle_name" maxlength="40" name="client-middle_name" type="text">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_client-last_name">Last name:</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_client-last_name" maxlength="40" name="client-last_name" type="text">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_client-adress">Adress:</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_client-adress" maxlength="40" name="client-adress" type="text">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_client-email">Email:</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_client-email" maxlength="75" name="client-email" type="email">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_client-phone_no">Phone no:</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_client-phone_no" maxlength="20" name="client-phone_no" type="text">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_client-mobile">Mobile:</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_client-mobile" maxlength="20" name="client-mobile" type="text">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_client-no_of_doctors">No of doctors:</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_client-no_of_doctors" name="client-no_of_doctors" type="number">
                            </div>



                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="user-data">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="id_personal_data-first_name">First name:</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_personal_data-first_name" maxlength="30" name="personal_data-first_name" type="text">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="id_personal_data-last_name">Last name:</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_personal_data-last_name" maxlength="30" name="personal_data-last_name" type="text">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="id_personal_data-email">Email:</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_personal_data-email" name="personal_data-email" type="text">
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="practice-details">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="id_practice_data-name">Name:</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_practice_data-name" maxlength="50" name="practice_data-name" type="text">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="id_practice_data-address">Address:</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_practice_data-address" maxlength="50" name="practice_data-address" type="text">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="id_practice_data-postal_code">Postal code:</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_practice_data-postal_code" maxlength="10" name="practice_data-postal_code" type="text">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="id_practice_data-phone_no">Phone no:</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_practice_data-phone_no" maxlength="10" name="practice_data-phone_no" type="text">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="id_practice_data-city">City:</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_practice_data-city" maxlength="10" name="practice_data-city" type="text">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="id_practice_data-logo">Logo:</label>
                            <input id="id_practice_data-logo" name="practice_data-logo" type="file">
                        </div>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="btn-register" name="register" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    </div>

</form>
```

Because I load forms using a prefix the name attribute looks like this "prefix-field_name". But this syntac can't be used with the plugin validator. So had to use selector. My setup for client-email was the following

```
$("#register-form").bootstrapValidator({

    fields:{

        id_client_email: {
            selector:"#id_client-email",
                validators: {
                    remote:{
                        url:"/order/email_check_availability/",
                        message: "This email already exists"
                     },
                    notEmpty:{
                        message: "This field is required"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But It won't seem to work, it won't show any errors. THe only error is when I start typing on the email field it says its not valid. But How can I add the extra validators? Is it because there is a name and I use a selector too? It doens't say anywhere in the docs that name always overwrites selector attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Worked!! I had to put fields that had a dash inside quotes. So field client-email had to be put like `"client-email"` in fields section in plugin